# Do I have copyright control of a transcript I created listening to a YouTube video?

Tags: copyright

If I transcribe the words to a song I listened to on YouTube, do I have a legal basis to sell the transcript?

Comment: Duplicate of [Is it legal to republish lyrics?](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/3920/is-it-legal-to-republish-lyrics), perhaps?

Comment: Well, think about it this way. Before that song could be created, those words had to exist on paper *somewhere*. The lyrics already exist in written form and are copyrighted as any other writing. You simply converting a song back to the words they started out as does not magically give you ownership over them. They still belong to whoever originally wrote them.

Answer (score 2):

No. Copyright rights only come into existence when creative decisions are made (with just a few narrow exceptions created by statute, none of which are relevant here). You just wrote what you heard, and there is nothing creative about that.

Note that this answer is correct for the United States. Other countries have other kinds of rights they also call copyright.

Answer (score 2):

From my courses on Swiss Copyright law:

It depends.

1. The transcript itself is not "new work" (similar to the creativity requirement mentioned in other answers)
2. Never the less, if you use Calligraphy or create a video of the lyrics moving in a unique way; that would be Copyrighted as a derivative creation since there is a creative element.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you have copyright in the derivative work of the transcript.

However, if you didn't get permission from the person who owns the copyright in the audio track of the video then by making the transcript you have breached their copyright and they can sue you. They would generally seek statutory damages but if your sales are hugely successful they can demand your profits.

You can try a fair use defense but making the transcript for profit generally precludes that.

Comment: Copyright protection does not extend to "derivatives" that don't add anything original (modicum of creativity standard): http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ14.pdf Lyrics transcribed from a music video do not give the transcriber any rights over that transcription.

Comment: Selling an otherwise infringing work profit does not generally preclude a finding of fair use: "commercial nature is only one element of the first factor enquiry into its purpose and character" ... "If, indeed, commerciality carried presumptive force against a finding of fairness, the presumption would swallow nearly all of the illustrative uses listed in the preamble paragraph" ... "the commercial or nonprofit educational character of a work is not conclusive". (Campbell v. Acuff-Rose Music, Inc. 510 U.S. 569 (1994))